# Mongodb add new field with type objectId

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to add a new field to all documents with type mongo ObjectId:

```
commentsId: [{type: db.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment'}]
```

Currently, I have something like this, which gives me '...' on Mongoshell.

```
db.bids.update({},{$set:[{"commentsId":[]}},false,true)
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Whats's   '...' on cmd mean?

Comment: I am not sure, but since the shell does not execute the query, it probably signify a shell error. I am using mongodb on windows, and whenever I make wrong query, it gives '...'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $set part of your query is wrong.  It should be an object and not an array, something like this:

```
db.bids.update({},{$set:{"commentsId":[]}},false,true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for inserting / updating new field to the existing data,

```
db.your_collection.update({},
                          {$set : {"new_field":1}},
                          {upsert:false,
                          multi:true})
```

You are putting `[` instead of `{`, *must be a typo.*

Your code should look like

```
db.bids.update({}, {$set : {"commentsId" : [] }}, false,true);
```